# how to do mean of redundant data in list-of-list of python?

Tags: python

I am new to programming and python. The list-of-list data that I have looks like this:

```
                  year,month,date_of_month,day_of_week,births 
combine_list =  [[2003, 12, 29, 1, 13125],
                 [2003, 12, 30, 2, 14700], 
                 [2003, 12, 31, 3, 12540], 
                 [2003, 12, 30, 2, 14700],
                 [2003, 12, 30, 2, 14438], 
                 .......................]]
```

As, you can see the second,fourth and fifth entries have same values for all fields except births. I have written a function to find mean of entries having redundant data :

```
 def distinct(file) :
        distinct_data = file
        for i in range(len(file)) :
            for j in range(i+1,len(file)) :
                if (i[0]==j[0] and i[1]==j[1] and i[2]==j[2] and i[3]==j[3]) :
                    disctinct_data = (i+j)/2
        return (distinct_data)

 distinctdata = distinct(combine_list)
```

But, interpreter throws me error :

```
 TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-19-70e5f515fb64> in <module>()
          7     return (distinct_data)
          8 
    ----> 9 distinctdata = distinct(combine_list)
         10 
         11 

    <ipython-input-19-70e5f515fb64> in distinct(file)
          3     for i in range(len(file)) :
          4         for j in range(i+1,len(file)) :
    ----> 5             if (i[0]==j[0] and i[1]==j[1] and i[2]==j[2] and i[3]==j[3]) :
          6                 disctinct_data = (i+j)/2
          7     return (distinct_data)

    TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Please, tell me where my function is wrong and what I can do to correct it.

Comment: i and j are just integers. You want to use somethingh like combined_list[i][0] == combined_list[j][0] to check for the list of list.

Comment: Instead of doing it your way, you should use a dictionary and store the elements as keys. Note that lists cannot be stored as keys, so you should pack the lists into tuples and then store as keys.

Comment: @Divyesh 'i' and 'j' are both just integer variables, they are not lists.You should use them to access your data, like 'file[i], file[j]'

Comment: @lordingtar I think a pandas or even numpy array would be even better

Comment: @AbidHasan you are correct, a pandas dataframe would be more scalable, but dictionaries do have an O(1) retrieval time, so it's not a bad way to store his entries

Comment: @AbidHasan Thanks. I will try something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use pandas for such operations http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html

With pandas You can find the mean using

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[2003, 12, 29, 1, 13125],
                 [2003, 12, 30, 2, 14700], 
                 [2003, 12, 31, 3, 12540], 
                 [2003, 12, 30, 2, 14700],
                 [2003, 12, 30, 2, 14438]], columns = ['year','month','date_of_month','day_of_week','births'])

df[df.duplicated(subset = ['year','month','date_of_month','day_of_week'])].mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the syntax error you were referring to. You were treating your element indexes as arrays:

```
combine_list =  [[2003, 12, 29, 1, 13125],
                 [2003, 12, 30, 2, 14700], 
                 [2003, 12, 31, 3, 12540], 
                 [2003, 12, 30, 2, 14700],
                 [2003, 12, 30, 2, 14438]]

def distinct(file) :
    distinct_data = file
    print(file)
    for i in range(len(file)) :
        for j in range(i+1,len(file)) :
            if (file[i][:3] == file[j][:3]) :
                disctinct_data = (i+j)/2
    return (distinct_data)

distinctdata = distinct(combine_list)
```